# Problemas con JWT Refresh Token y Unix Time

Tags: symfony, jwt, timestamp

Estoy utilizando [JWTRefreshTokenBundle](https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle) en un proyecto de Symfony con API-Platform donde toda la gestión de fechas la hago con el formato **Unix_Time** de ahí que cuando realizo la petición para refrescar el token recibo un error diciéndome que No puede convertirse el objeto DateTime a int (***Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int***)

[image: metodo isValid]

[image: metodo para validación del refresh token]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto y no como imagen. Pro favor leer [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras lo que agrego son las excepciones que muestra el framework, no mi código